# Seeing colors properly through colored glass

Tags: shaders, transparency, glass

I have this simple model of a youtube Icon and I'm trying to make the red part transparent red but at the same time see the white triangle pure white.
[image: The transparent red youtube logo]

Comment: Why not putting the white triangle outside of the red jelly? Or both a bit like a stained glass, white solid triangle in the center and red transparent around  ?

Comment: You could use the Compositor to overlay the 2 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if something like this is what you wanna achieve:

[image]

i used an HDRI and i "cheated" to get the white color of the triangle by giving it a massive emission:

[image]

Red shader:

[image]

this is with less emission and a bevel for the red part:

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks for the help.